# Invalid identifier in double-nested query with ORDER BY and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, sql-order-by, rownum

I'm on Oracle and I need to use both, `ORDER BY` and `ROWNUM`, in one request. I need to double-nest my inner query, because I want to apply `ORDER BY` **first** and select with `ROWNUM=1` **afterwards**.

My data is filtered by `O.ID` on outmost level. However, I get an error in my inner query, because `O.ID` is an **unknown identifier** there.

What I want:

```
SELECT
  O.INSERTDATE OrderCreateDate,

  -- Determine delivery date
  (SELECT INSERTDATE FROM (
     SELECT OP2.FK_ORDER, DD.ID, DD.INSERTDATE FROM MY_DELIVERYDATE_TABLE DD
       JOIN MY_ORDERPOS_TABLE OP2 ON DD.FK_ORDERPOS=OP2.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
       WHERE OP2.FK_ORDER=O.ID AND -- This gives me "Invalid identifier O.ID"
             DD.DELFLAG IS NULL AND OP2.DELFLAG IS NULL
       ORDER BY DD.CLOSED ASC, ABS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DD.INSERTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY'))) ASC
  ) WHERE ROWNUM=1) DeliveryDate

FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE O
WHERE O.ID = 620; -- ID goes here!
```

The only way I get this working, is when I filter in the `WHERE` clause of the intermediate `SELECT` query. But this is slow, of course, since the inner SQL returns the entire data without filtering.

```
SELECT
  O.INSERTDATE OrderCreateDate,

  -- Determine delivery date
  (SELECT INSERTDATE FROM (
     SELECT OP2.FK_ORDER, DD.ID, DD.INSERTDATE FROM MY_DELIVERYDATE_TABLE DD
       JOIN MY_ORDERPOS_TABLE OP2 ON DD.FK_ORDERPOS=OP2.ID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
       WHERE DD.DELFLAG IS NULL AND OP2.DELFLAG IS NULL
       ORDER BY DD.CLOSED ASC, ABS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DD.INSERTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY'))) ASC
  ) WHERE ROWNUM=1 AND FK_ORDER=O.ID) DeliveryDate -- Filtering here

FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE O
WHERE O.ID = 620;
```

How can I pass `O.ID` to the inner query or how can this query be redesigned, still keeping `ORDER BY` and `ROWNUM` work.

---

**My final solution** as suggested by Kim Berg Hansen and improved by rims:

(I had to use `MIN()` instead of `MAX()`, though)

```
SELECT
  O.INSERTDATE OrderCreateDate,

  -- Determine delivery date
  (SELECT MIN(DD.INSERTDATE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY
    DD.CLOSED ASC, ABS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-TRUNC(DD.INSERTDATE))) ASC)
   FROM MY_DELIVERYDATE_TABLE DD
   JOIN MY_ORDERPOS_TABLE OP2 ON DD.FK_ORDERPOS=OP2.ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
   WHERE OP2.FK_ORDER=O.ID AND
         DD.DELFLAG IS NULL AND OP2.DELFLAG IS NULL
  ) DeliveryDate

FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE O
WHERE O.ID = 620; -- ID goes here!
```

Comment: Those are large queries.  The relevant parts don't exactly stand out.  See if you can filter out irrelevant stuff and post a simple example that reproduces the problem

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you can simplify / improve query by using [TRUNC(date)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm) to drop time part from date-time. Change: `TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DD.INSERTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY')` to `TRUNC(DD.INSERTDATE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scalar subquery you are using, you can only reference the tables from the "main" query "one nested level down", not any further down, as you have seen. (I believe this restriction is lifted in version 12, so maybe you can just upgrade your database? ;-)

In the scalar subquery you are trying to get the value of INSERTDATE column of the first row according to your ordering. That can also be written without nesting as follows:

```
SELECT
O.INSERTDATE OrderCreateDate,

-- Determine delivery date
(SELECT MAX(DD.INSERTDATE) KEEP (
          DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY
          DD.CLOSED ASC, ABS(TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE-TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(DD.INSERTDATE, 'DDMMYYYY'), 'DDMMYYYY'))) ASC
        )
   FROM MY_DELIVERYDATE_TABLE DD
   JOIN MY_ORDERPOS_TABLE OP2 ON DD.FK_ORDERPOS=OP2.ID
   LEFT OUTER JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
   WHERE OP2.FK_ORDER=O.ID AND -- This will no longer give "Invalid identifier O.ID"
         DD.DELFLAG IS NULL AND OP2.DELFLAG IS NULL
) DeliveryDate

FROM MY_ORDER_TABLE O
WHERE O.ID = 620; -- ID goes here!
```

KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST tells the MAX function, that it should calculate the MAX *only* of those rows that rank *first* in the ORDER BY clause. So if your ORDER BY is "unique", MAX will be applied only to *one* row. If your ORDER BY is not "unique" and can have duplicates, you might think about whether you want the MAX or the MIN (or add something to the ORDER BY to make it unique.)

(If you had been on Oracle version 12, an alternative to the KEEP (DENSE_RANK trick would be to use the FIRST 1 ROW ONLY clause of the SELECT statement.)

Comment: Thank you. I had a closer look at analytic functions today and I could apply the pattern you suggested to another use case also. Very useful feature Oracle provides here!