# Pass id to inner SELECT of nested query with ORDER BY and ROWNUM

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, sql-order-by, rownum

I am facing a similar problem, [I had a couple of months ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25616529): I need to return a single value from a subquery that may or may not return a list of values. Thus, I apply `ORDER BY` first and select the topmost entry with `WHERE ROWNUM=1` then (*Yep, I'm on Oracle*).

**The problem is, the required ID in the inner query is unknown due to nesting.**

Last time, I was adviced to use Oracles analytic functions and apply `MIN()`/`MAX()`. This time, however, I'm selecting a currency symbol (`VARCHAR`) and cannot utilize these functions.

Any help is greatly appreciated. This is the relevant part of my query:

```
SELECT
  MyOtherColumn,

  (SELECT CurrencySymbol FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT P2.ID, P2.VALIDFROMDATE, CURR.CURRENCYSYMBOL AS CurrencySymbol FROM MY_ORDER_TABLEPOS OP2
     JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
     JOIN MY_PRICE_TABLE P2 ON OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE=P2.FK_ARTICLE
     JOIN MY_CURRENCY_TABLE CURR ON P2.FK_CURRENCY=CURR.ID
     WHERE OP2.FK_ORDER=O.ID AND P2.ID=( -- This fails, since O.ID is unknown in inner query!
       -- Determine current price for article
       SELECT MAX(P3.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY P3.MINTOORDER DESC, P3.VALIDFROMDATE DESC) CurrentPriceId
       FROM MY_PRICE_TABLE P3
       WHERE P3.FK_ARTICLE=OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE
       AND P3.VALIDFROMDATE<=SYSDATE
       AND P3.MINTOORDER<=OP2.AMOUNT
     )
     ORDER BY P2.VALIDFROMDATE DESC
  )
  WHERE ROWNUM=1) CurrencySymbol

FROM ...
WHERE O.ID=786;
```

Adding an ID to the inner query

```
SELECT DISTINCT P2.ID, P2.VALIDFROMDATE, CURR.CURRENCYSYMBOL AS CurrencySymbol FROM MY_ORDER_TABLEPOS OP2
JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
JOIN MY_PRICE_TABLE P2 ON OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE=P2.FK_ARTICLE
JOIN MY_CURRENCY_TABLE CURR ON P2.FK_CURRENCY=CURR.ID
WHERE OP2.FK_ORDER=786 AND P2.ID=( -- ID was set statically here
 -- Determine current price for article
 SELECT MAX(P3.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY P3.MINTOORDER DESC, P3.VALIDFROMDATE DESC) CurrentPriceId
 FROM MY_PRICE_TABLE P3
 WHERE P3.FK_ARTICLE=OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE
 AND P3.VALIDFROMDATE<=SYSDATE
 AND P3.MINTOORDER<=OP2.AMOUNT
)
ORDER BY P2.VALIDFROMDATE DESC;
```

gets me this result:

```
ID     VALIDFROMDATE                  CURRENCYSYMBOL
597    18.11.14 00:00:00,000000000    $
556    10.11.14 10:54:05,973000000    €
552    10.11.14 10:44:25,719000000    €
258    15.10.14 10:12:01,670000000    €
```

My goal is to return the `CURRENCYSYMBOL` of the topmost entry (here: `$`).

So, my question is: How can I pass the order ID to the nested query or how can I rewrite the query such that it meets my needs? I know the query is overly complex, my apologies for that. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
  (SELECT CurrencySymbol FROM (
     SELECT OP2.FK_ORDER, CURR.CURRENCYSYMBOL AS CurrencySymbol,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OP2.FK_ORDER ORDER BY P2.VALIDFROMDATE DESC) RW
     FROM MY_ORDER_TABLEPOS OP2
         JOIN MY_ORDER_TABLE O2 ON OP2.FK_ORDER=O2.ID
         JOIN MY_PRICE_TABLE P2 ON OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE=P2.FK_ARTICLE
         JOIN MY_CURRENCY_TABLE CURR ON P2.FK_CURRENCY=CURR.ID
     WHERE P2.ID=(
       -- Determine current price for article
       SELECT MAX(P3.ID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY P3.MINTOORDER DESC, P3.VALIDFROMDATE DESC) CurrentPriceId
       FROM MY_PRICE_TABLE P3
       WHERE P3.FK_ARTICLE=OP2.FK_CONCRETARTICLE
       AND P3.VALIDFROMDATE<=SYSDATE
       AND P3.MINTOORDER<=OP2.AMOUNT
     )
  )
  WHERE FK_ORDER = O.ID AND RW=1) CurrencySymbol
```

Comment: Thank you, but the inner query ``SELECT OP2.FK_ORDER, CURR.CURRENCYSYMBOL AS CurrencySymbol...`` will return results for **all** possible FK_ORDER ids. In terms of performance, this seems problematic. Is there no possibility to pass the id to the inner query?

Comment: @user1438038 Move your correlated subquery from SELECT to FROM ... Take a note that your subquery is executed for each O.ID, my version is executed only once (however, there can be performance issues). I don't know the nature of your data, I even don't know what's behind FROM ... you asked to rewrite the query and gave only a select list. Performance issues it's another question I suppose

Comment: Please don't get me wrong, I appreciate your effort. However, I have to keep performance in mind. In terms of correctness, your query is a big improvement for me already.